# Box with 100% in width are not center on page

Tags: css, centering

I'm trying to center a box across the screen to have my content in it. The problem is that when I set `top` at `50%` the box will not be 100% center on the page. It's like 60% on top and 40% on bottom.

Here's the HTML code:

```
​<div class="content">
    test
</div>​
```

And here is the stylesheet:

```
body, html {
    color: #eaeaea;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/cceSw/

What have I missed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to minus the height of the div from your `top` too. This can be done by setting a negative margin on the `margin-top`.

Have a look here - this is an update to your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cceSw/3/

I added a `height` and `margin-top` to your `.content`

```
.content {
background-color: #000000;
padding: 10px 15px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
width: 100%;
height:50%;
margin-top:-25%;
```

}​

If it's likely your content is going to be different sizes then you can use JQuery to calculate its height and dynamically set its margin.

Comment: Many thanks :) Your solution worked like a charm ^^ I'll accept it when I can

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a negative top margin which should be 50% of the height of the div.